# Debugging beginner C crash, looking for alternate logic with bug found

Tags: c, string, debugging, loops, null

I was doing a study on a program which is working (mostly) and... I ran into a bug that causes a complete crash in the system at the finish line. After print-screening to pinpoint the leak, I'm reasonably sure I've found the gremlin in it's hiding spot, but I can't think of any bug spray solution to this!

Would any of you have ideas or advice on solving this puzzle? I think a fresh pair of eyes would do wonders! I definitely appreciate your time, I'm pretty sure it's really something simple at the end of it all! >_<

Thank you for any comment or suggestions!

---

### **Information about the program + script**:

---

1. **Take any number** of user-input *(numbers only)* **strings**

   - When user inputs an empty string, the program will detect that as the end of user inputs, and proceed with wrapping things up.
2. **tokenize** and convert **each token to integers.**
3. **Add the ints** into dynamically allocated database.

---

**Here are anomalies I found**

- **Main_Size** always has a **final result 1 above** what it *should* be.
- **The error likely stems from the loop() function** I created. Normally when a user inputs an empty string, that should be the end of it. But the program seems to count that empty string and ship it off into the assembly, where a NULL value eventually gets housed into the main int-array. I'm *almost* 100% positive that's where my error is. I've tried multiple different ways to detecting a null string and avoid sending that to the rest of assembly, but no luck so far :(
- The aggressive print-debugging I used seems to "break formation" at the final round of printing a single string. **There's an additional line break**, and I have no idea how it got there.
- Using a scanf prompt to signal end of user-input strings yields good results, but the moment more than one string are entered before the end, the program goes haywire.

---

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 12
#define MIN_SIZE 2

int loop(int* Main_Array, char str[], int Main_Size);
int* Create_Main_Array();
int Input_String(char str[]);
int Token_Atoi(char str[], int numElements, int* Main_Array, int Main_Size);
int Dynamic_Fitting(int* Main_Array , int Incomming_int , int Main_Size);
void Free_All(int* Main_Array);

//////////////////// 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
   char str[MAX_SIZE];
   int* Main_Array = Create_Main_Array(), Main_Size = 0;
   //Main_Size = The number of elements currently in the dynamic memory. 
   //This number should increase by 1 for every new int you add into the 
   //array, starting from zero, as in Main_Array[0] = ####

   Main_Size = loop(Main_Array, str, Main_Size);

   printf("\n\nMain_Size final size is: %i\n", Main_Size);

   for(int i=0; i<Main_Size; i++)
           printf("Check: %i \n", Main_Array[i]);
   Free_All(Main_Array);

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Sets up Dynamic Space. It will be realloced in the future. 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int* Create_Main_Array()
{
     return (int*)malloc(MAX_SIZE*sizeof(int));
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Calls up the user to input a string. 
//Loops the entire process so long as returned string is larger then 0.
//Returns total Element size of Main, after it's been modified in the program.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int loop(int* Main_Array, char str[], int Main_Size)
{
   int numElements;
   while(numElements>0)
   {
      numElements = Input_String(str);
      //for some reason, at the very end of the loop, it will tag on another '\0' 
      //into the Main_Array, which causes a crash. Likely the setup at line 52.
      Main_Size = Token_Atoi(str, numElements, Main_Array, Main_Size);
   }
   return Main_Size;   
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Enters strings, and returns size of the strings.
//Will not count Line breaks as a character. 
//Going under or over a limit will trigger a reroute. 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int Input_String(char str[])
{
   printf("\nPlease input a string of numbers.\n");
   printf("Tap enter again once finnished: \n\n");
   int i=0;
   while ((str[i] = getchar()) != '\n')
      i++;
   str[i+1]='\0';
   return i;

   if (i>MAX_SIZE-1 || i<MIN_SIZE)
      {
         printf("Your sumbition dosn't fit the size criteria.\n");
         printf("Please reenter:\n\n");
         Input_String(str);
      }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Tolkenizes string, Atoi each token into cute little ints.
//Each int will be sent to the Dynamic_Fitting to be assimilated into Main_Array
//Main_Size is passed into this function just to be used as parameters for the fitting.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int Token_Atoi(char str[], int numElements, int* Main_Array, int Main_Size)
{
   char* temp = strtok(str, " -");

   int i=0;
   while (temp != NULL)
   {         
         printf("String tokenize check: %s\n", temp);
         Main_Size = Dynamic_Fitting(Main_Array, atoi(temp), Main_Size);
         //Main size should be upgraded with each loop of the above line. 
         temp = strtok(NULL, " -");
         i++;
   }
   return Main_Size;     
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Will first increase the size of the dynamically allocated array of ints by 1 int
//Then, it will add the incomming int into the re-sized dynamic space. 
//Main size serves as a bookmark to show where on the array the new realloc'd spot should be. 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int Dynamic_Fitting(int* Main_Array , int Incomming_int , int Main_Size)
{
    realloc(Main_Array, sizeof(int));
    Main_Array[Main_Size]= Incomming_int;
    printf("Dynamic fitting check: %i put into Main_Array[%i]\n\n", Incomming_int, Main_Size);
    return Main_Size+1;
}   

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Close shop 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Free_All(int* Main_Array)
{
   free(Main_Array);
}
```

Comment: 1. **If you use flower boxes,** at least do so using `/****/`, since `//////` is terrible. 2. `realloc(Main_Array, sizeof(int));` doesn't do any good (check the docs to see `realloc()` returns a pointer *for some reason...* - also think about why it takes a size argument); 3. Caps_For_Var_Names, especially with underscores interspersed, are ugly, choose one of `under_scores` or `camelCaps`.

Comment: I'll work with /****/ from now on, and work on the naming conventions you mentioned! More study for me about realloc is in the future, I thought I'd understood it well enough from the realloc() explanations on the net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
realloc(Main_Array, sizeof(int));
```

is wrong.  [realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) returns a pointer that may point to new memory so when you dereference `Main_Array` on the next line you may be accessing freed memory.  Also, you need to pass the full size of the updated memory buffer, not just the delta.

You could fix things by changing `Dynamic_Fitting` to something like

```
int Dynamic_Fitting(int** Main_Array , int Incomming_int , int Main_Size)
{
    int* temp = realloc(Main_Array, (Main_Size +1) * sizeof(int));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return -1; /* caller must handle oom error */
    }
    *Main_Array = temp;
    (*Main_Array)[Main_Size] = Incomming_int;
    printf("Dynamic fitting check: %i put into Main_Array[%i]\n\n", Incomming_int, Main_Size);
    return Main_Size+1;
}
```

and calling it like

```
Main_Size = Dynamic_Fitting(&Main_Array, ....);
if (Main_Size == -1) {
    /* out of memory.  cleanup and exit program */
}
```

Comment: Man, that took me by surprise, I was sure I had realloc down >:
I did trials with your new code sections, modified it a bit to fit in, and it no longer causes my program to crash which is a pretty awesome win right there! Main still comes out as +1 above normal, and gives an additional 0 value to the final Main_Array[Main_Size] like it's done before, but now the problems a lot more manageable!

As for Valigrid, I've never heard of it, but I'm pretty stoked when I found out what it was, definitely will be using this in the future

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is one of the issue. 
you have shared a very bog code and analysing everything is bit of a task... see if below issue solves your issu..

```
int Input_String(char str[])
{
   printf("\nPlease input a string of numbers.\n");
   printf("Tap enter again once finnished: \n\n");
   int i=0;
   while ((str[i] = getchar()) != '\n') //  HERE if user enters more than array Size it will fail... with exception
      i++;
   str[i+1]='\0';
   return i; /// THIS is wrong.. following if will never execute..

   if (i>MAX_SIZE-1 || i<MIN_SIZE)
      {
         printf("Your sumbition dosn't fit the size criteria.\n");
         printf("Please reenter:\n\n");
         Input_String(str);
      }
}
```

I will suggest below

```
int Input_String(char str[])
    {
       printf("\nPlease input a string of numbers.\n");
       printf("Tap enter again once finnished: \n\n");
       int i=0;
       while ((str[i] = getchar()) != '\n') {
          i++;
          if (i>MAX_SIZE-1 || i<MIN_SIZE)
          {
             printf("Your sumbition dosn't fit the size criteria.\n");
             printf("Please reenter:\n\n");
             Input_String(str);
             break;
          }

      }
       str[i+1]='\0';
       return i; 
         }
```

Comment: I'll give it a go using this after I've studied Simonc's answer, to compare and contrast. Thanks for this!

EDIT: The program flips around with the size confliction even if the input is within the normal limits. However, it did give me some more info on one extra bug that is now confirmed as a stand-alone problem - the main array getting one extra value added to it's end